# Change output of itertools

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
import itertools
def x(a,b):
    x = [[i] for i in itertools.product(a, repeat=b)]
    return [x]
print (x({0,1},3))
```

The output is

```
[[[(0, 0, 0)], [(0, 0, 1)], [(0, 1, 0)], [(0, 1, 1)], [(1, 0, 0)], [(1, 0, 1)], [(1, 1,    0)], [(1, 1, 1)]]]
```

What I am wanting is for it to look like this, all the () removed and the starting and finishing [] removed

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
return list(itertools.product(a, repeat=b))
```

or, if you want the elements to all be lists,

```
return map(list, itertools.product(a, repeat=b))
```

Also, be careful writing to a variable named `x` from within a function named `x`; this is going to cause trouble for recursion.

Comment: Because I am needing the output to be
    [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]] 
the code you have given has the same problem as mine it has (0,0,0)where I want [0,0,0]

Comment: The second piece of code works perfectly in python 2.7, but not in python 3 would you know what i have to change for it to work in python 3